# Android Nearby not working on Android Things

Tags: android, android-things, google-nearby

I have have the following code:

```
OnFailureListener onFailureListener = new OnFailureListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "bum", e);
  }
};
connectionsClient.startAdvertising("Device A", getPackageName(), myCallback, new AdvertisingOptions(STRATEGY))
        .addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener);
```

If I run in on my phone it works as expected, but when I run it on my Android Things device I get the following error

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE(8050): null
```

From what I have noticed so far, my phone has Google Play Services version 12.8.72, but the Android Things image has Google Play Services 12.5.20

Anyone else had the same issue, and found a solution for it?

Comment: I fond a phone with Google Play Services version 12.6.85 and got the same error as on the Android Things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to [Varun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51428134), I'm going to guess that the default launcher is still running and hogging Connections. The [IoT launcher](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/android-things-developer-preview-6.html) will look something like this:

[image]

You can make your app the home app by adding an intent-filter to the manifest, like so ([official documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0#home-activity-support)):

```
<application
android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
    <!-- Launch activity as default from Android Studio -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Launch activity automatically on boot, and re-launch if the app terminates. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Once you add the intent-filter to your manifest and install + run your app, you'll want to make sure the default launcher is no longer running. The easiest way to do this is to just reboot your Android Things device. Since your app is now the home app, it'll be the first app to launch after the reboot.

I'm not sure what Android Things version/system image you have, but you might also be able to do with one of the following adb commands:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.iotlauncher.ota
```

or maybe:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.iotlauncher
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, just want to add that no need to add "Home" Category in the intent filter, just force stop "iotlauncher" will work, and back button also land you again on home screen aka launcher screen

Answer (score 3):

The version of Play Services is fixed to each release on Android Things, not updated automatically through the Play Store (see [Google Services](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started/google-services) for more details on how Play Service works on Android Things). Because of this, you need to select a client library version for Nearby that will work with the 12.5.20 Play Services APK.

You may have success with a later version as well, but `12.0.1` is a known tested version of the Nearby client with Android Things 1.0.x:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:12.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to use ```"com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:12.0.1"``` but it did not help.

Comment: @Zlatko I have successfully connected to NearBy API using 16.0.0 version, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51428433/1232051

Comment: This was the most promising version from what I tried but stil lgetting error about missing class Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AdvertisingOptions. Anyone solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Error code 8050 is API_CONNECTION_FAILED_ALREADY_IN_USE -- you can read more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsStatusCodes).

Essentially, Nearby Connections doesn't (yet) support multiple clients using it, so there's some other app already using it that needs to be killed -- it's likely to be the app that sets up your Android Things device.