# Google Nearby not working on Android Things by default

Tags: android, android-things, google-nearby

I'm developing an Android Things application on the iMX7D development board and I have implemented Google's Nearby services. The issue I have is that I get an error (sometimes) when I begin advertising the device. Here is the error:

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device.

I have managed to fix the error by following the instructions on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51428433/6377151, and that allows the code to run fine. The error gets fixed if I run the ADB command

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.iotlauncher.ota
```

And then run the application, but that only works for the one time. As soon as the device is rebooted, the issue comes back. I'm aware that this is because the default launcher is already advertising the device, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue in code automatically when my application runs. But I need a way to either do this automatically on startup or to overcome the error in another way.

My Android Things device is running Android Things 1.0.10. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work on Nearby.

We have a release ready to allow multiple apps to advertise/scan at the same time. It's code-complete, but code pushes are slow at Google. It'll be a while before it's public. Note: Android Things boards might need to be reflashed to get the update. That was the case in development, but is hopefully not the case for release builds.

In the meantime, you'll unfortunately have to either install another launcher, or force stop the existing one. We treat clients as first-come-first-serve.

Comment: That sounds great. How long do you think it'll take to become public? Is it normally weeks or months?

Comment: Looking at the schedule, roughly mid-May.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on workarounds until this?

Comment: Installing another Android launcher app is my best suggestion.